# How to get the selected item from GridView in Xamarin form application

Tags: gridview, xamarin.forms, selecteditem

I have used GridView control on my view with a local DataTemplate but i am not able to find a appropriate way to get the selected items when user clicks on any grid item. I have View model class but doesn't get anything particular to get the selected item. I cannot use listview as i need to use show data in grid columns.

```
<grial:GridView  
                    x:Name="SamplesGrid"
                Grid.Row="0"
                ColumnCount="3"
                ColumnSpacing="15"
                RowSpacing="10"
                Padding="20, 20, 20, 20"
                ItemHeight="120"

                ItemsSource="{ Binding Samples }">
                        <grial:GridView.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:DashboardItemTemplate
                            ShowBackgroundImage="false"
                            ShowBackgroundColor="False"
                            ShowiconColoredCircleBackground="True"
                            TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </grial:GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    </grial:GridView>
```

Comment: Which custom control is this can you link it?

Comment: <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  Tapped="HandleEvent"/>
 </Grid.GestureRecognizers> . you can try something like this

Comment: @PragneshMistry That is not the Grid Control

Comment: @G.hakim oh yes

Comment: @zesshan https://docs.grialkit.com/grid-view.html -> There is a very clear instruction about handling ItemClickCommand in the above link, do check it out.